# Why do I have to create a server with http.createServer when using websockets?

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

This is a piece of code from **Socket io** docs:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
```

almost the same code as for **ws**:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
```

And my question here is why should I create a server like this:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

passing **express** instance to a `http.createServer()` method when **app** itself is already a ready-to-be-used server?

What's the difference between those two instances in this case?

`app = express();` and `server = http.createServer(app);`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [express API docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), `express()` creates an express application, while `http.createServer()` actually returns an HTTP Server.

We would pass the express application as a parameter into the `createServer` method to create an express server.

Check out the `createServer` [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener) for more info.